# Black Screens & Scrambled Screen on Boot

Tags: motherboard, crash

CPU: Intel Core i5-760 (Overclocked to 3.8Ghz 19x200 on stock voltage) + Noctua nh-d14
MOBO: Asus Sabertooth i55
MEM: Kingston Hyper X Black Edition DDR3-1600 ( 4x 2GB )
GPU: MSI GTX 470 Twin Frozr (SLI)
PSU: Cooler Master 850W Silent Pro M

Old Picture of my Setup:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B201mQSmf6kKMVFoN1hLSThiNFU/edit

I've had this system for about 3 Years now. And I've always had the occasional black screen. (then rarely)
Thought it were just Geforce driver blurps but they've been getting a lot more frequent lately with
now having scrambled boot screens before turning to black. This can leave me trying to boot the PC for 15 minutes
before finally getting into windows and then running stable.

Unhappy Moment:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B201mQSmf6kKUEFIUUhrdUpWNVU/edit

I've had this with my system overclocked or not, with SLI, one card or switched with the other.
Correct drivers installed, newest Bios, all in order. So I can be sure that the CPU nor GPUs are not to blame. (Phew!)

My USB ports will also randomly drop connection if I have a lot of USB devices in there (even when set behind a powered USB hub ).
Back in the day I could even trigger this by doing something like color picking in Autodesk Mudbox. Or back when I was doing 3D Surround this would happen all the time.
Back then I almost sent the PSU back but I ended up not doing it, cuz I actually REALLY need my PC for work.

And I've recently noticed that sometimes 1/4 leds on my fans starts blinking (connected to the motherboard).
At times like this I really wish I worked in a computer hardware store so that I could test these things out. :/

So what do you guys think ? Faulty MOBO or Faulty PSU ? Any help is duly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i would do is reduce the system to only what is necessary to post. That way you eliminate all unnecessary peripherals that could be drawing power. This allows you to sort of test to see if you are under powering your system. If your issues are resolved then your PSU should be tested or replaced with a more powerful PSU with very heavy 12v amperage.

If the issues persist at that point, with little power consumption, the only real way to know would be to try a different PSU and see if you still have trouble.

You may also want to take one of your GPUs and test each PCIe slot independently. You could have a bad slot on the board.

One other thing to check would be your front panel connectors. They could be creating a short to ground, and that would explain some of the behavior, but not likely for the screen issues.

As an educated guess I would lean towards motherboard personally, only because of the garbage screen. With a faulty or underpowered power supply I would not expect that sort of response, but it is possible.

Best of luck.